# Why do I get a 500 error when registering a leadNotification subscription with the LinkedIn Lead Sync API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working with the LinkedIn [Lead Sync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-sync/leadsync?view=li-lms-2023-09&tabs=http) and I am trying to create a [Lead notification subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-sync/leadsync?view=li-lms-2023-09&tabs=http#create-leadgen-notification-subscription---owner-level) but I keep getting a `500 Internal Server` error from LinkedIn. I have taken their API endpoint parameters and headers to recreate their examples exactly but nothing helps to solve the error. The confusing part I am seeing though is even though I get the 500 error it still registers and validates the Webhook in the backend of LinkedIn and I am able to see it when refreshing the Webhook page. Also if I run the Notification Subscription API request a second time I get the expected `201` response.

I have tried using different `LinkedIn-Version` values from `202307`, `202308`, and `202309` with no success. I have also tried excluding/including the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` to see if that would change the outcome of the request but nothing changed either. I have also tried PUT, and POST for the method type and only POST works for this endpoint. I have also checked to make sure that my webhook URL has a valid SSL certificate installed which it does (Let's Encrypt).

### Fetch Request

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("LinkedIn-Version", "202308");
myHeaders.append("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append(
  "Authorization",
  "Bearer TOKEN_VALUE"
);

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  webhook: "https://example.com/validate_webhook.php",
  owner: {
    sponsoredAccount: "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:999999999",
  },
  leadType: "SPONSORED",
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow",
};

fetch("https://api.linkedin.com/rest/leadNotifications", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

### Error Response

```json
{
    "status": 500,
    "code": "SERVICE_INTERNAL_ERROR",
    "message": "Error encountered when calling /leadNotifications"
}
```

I am not sure what else I can try at this point and would like any help I can get on this issue.

Thanks!