# LinkedIn API endpoint leadNotifications throws 500

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to `/leadNotifications` but getting a 500

```
    "status": 500,
    "code": "SERVICE_INTERNAL_ERROR",
    "message": "Error encountered when calling /leadNotifications"
```

I checked the LinkedIn server status and it seems the issue is actually not the server.

This is my curl request:

```
curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/leadNotifications' \
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202307' \
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "webhook": "https://www.example.com",
    "owner": {
        "sponsoredAccount": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:111111111"
    },
    "leadType": "SPONSORED"
}'
```

My Authentication should be fine as the acces token works with other endpoint `/adAccounts`
Just to confirm I added all the neccessary scopes to my app/auth: r_marketing_leadgen_automation, rw_ads, r_ads

I tried different LeadType and different version headers but keep getting the above err.

Appreciate any help

Thanks

ps, Someone else had a similar issue [Why do I get a 500 error when registering a leadNotification subscription with the LinkedIn Lead Sync API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77190947/why-do-i-get-a-500-error-when-registering-a-leadnotification-subscription-with-t)